# PHP как проверить с какой страницы пришел запрос?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, url

Мне нужно убедиться, что запрос в скрипт приходит с моего сервера. Я нашел `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, но он показывает только относительный путь к самому файлу `(/order/order.php)`. Я использую скрипт через ajax, может в этом проблема?

Как мне получить полный путь или как убедиться, что запрос с моего сервера?

Answer (score 4):

Есть заголовок Referrer, который показывает откуда пришел запрос. Браузер может не отправить эту информацию, и тогда узнать нельзя.

Если браузер отправил эту информацию, то она лежит в $SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']

Информация из [официальной PHP документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php):

> Адрес страницы (если есть), которая привела браузер пользователя на
>   эту страницу. Этот заголовок устанавливается веб-браузером
>   пользователя. Не все браузеры устанавливают его и некоторые в качестве
>   дополнительной возможности позволяют изменять содержимое заголовка
>   HTTP_REFERER. Одним словом, в самом деле ему нельзя доверять.

Если вы хотите сделать защиту от подделки запросов, вы можете добавить не угадываемый токен, известный только вашему серверу, в каждый запрос. При этом способе, если запрос приходит без подходящего токена, ему будет отказано в доступе, обычно это используют при защите от CSRF, которая приводит к тому, что хакер может выполнить на неподготовленном сайте массу различных действий от имени других, зарегистрированных посетителей.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно генерировать `csrf` токен писать его в сессию и генерировать в поле на странице. После отправляете токен в запросе и сравниваете в backend если они равны ( токен с сессии и токен пришедший со страницы) то запрос отправлен точно с вашей страницы.